# Python CSV to JSON is quoting nested objects

Tags: python, json, csv, quotes

I am using the following to convert a CSV file to JSON. The problem is, any nested objects get quoted. How can I fix this so that I can pass the output to an endpoint?

```
def csvToJson(tokenHeader):
data = []
with open('CSV/quiz-questions.csv') as questionFile:
    csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(questionFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        row = {key: (None if value == "" else value) for key, value in row.items()}
        row = {key: ([] if value == "[]" else value) for key, value in row.items()}
        data.append(json.dumps(row, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output Snippet:

```
"question": "{'guid': ...
```

Comment: what is the format of the csv file? Does your csv flat file emulate nested data?

Comment: I just wrote to a csv from an endpoint:

   
    file = open('CSV/quiz-questions.csv', 'w')
 
    csvwriter = csv.writer(file)

Comment: why are you using `json.dumps()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by handling things on the writing side. When passing my questions into the CSV, I was creating a dictionary with my nested objects. This was causing headaches when reading from the CSV. So now I use this line to fix my nested objects:

```
question = {key: (json.dumps(value) if key in ['question', etc. etc.] else value) for key, value in question.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to read a csv into a list of dictionaries with column: value structure:

```py
import csv

def open_csv(path):
    '''return a list of dictionaries
    '''
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        # simple way to do the replacements, but do you really need to do this?
        return [{k: [] if v == '[]' else v or None
                 for k, v in dict(row).items()}
                for row in reader]

data = open_csv('test.txt')

# output to json because it looks better, null is None
import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

test.csv

```
name,age,hobby,countries
foo,31,,"['123', 'abc']"
bar,60,python programming,[]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "age": "31",
        "hobby": null,
        "countries": "['123', 'abc']"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "age": "60",
        "hobby": "python programming",
        "countries": []
    }
]
```